# Recurrent inline versus function within function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, operators, wrapper

I have a situation where I'm writing multiple functions that share a method of work and would really like to refactor and tidy up this code, rather than having these same blocks occur countless times only to execute slight differences. Given a block of information, I scan through each entry and perform operations on the block in question. An example of the recurrent function is as follows:

```
    function basicFunc() {
        var totalX = 2000, totalY = 2000;
        for (var y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
                  /* Fake operation for theory */
                  var fakeVar = (y * x);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comparative to:

```
    function eachBlock(whatToDo, totalX, totalY) {
        for (var y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
                 /* Fake operation for theory */
                 return whatToDo;

            }
        }
    };
    function basicFunc() {
        var totalX = 2000, totalY = 2000;
        eachoBlock("var fakeVar = (y * x)", totalX, totalY);
    };
```

This works fine for single lines to be passed as the `whatToDo` parameter. How would you go about passing multiple lines to `eachBlock()`, say if you have a bunch of operations to do instead of the one `var FakeVar` operation?

**TLDR:** How can you use a function call within a function to wrap the original block of code operations it performed before becoming a separate function?

Comment: No semicolons necessary after blocks (e.g. function bodies), by the way.

Comment: Why don't you simply pass a function as `whatToDo` instead of a string 'full of operations'?

Comment: That is exactly the gist I'm getting at Tyblitz. I don't know of the best or correct practice to do exactly that.

Comment: Oh! That's simple: You can either include a non-named function in your eachBlock function (like minitech's answer), or store the operations you want to perform in another named function like you've done for eachBlock. Like so:

`1) function whatToDo1() { var fakeVar = (y * x); }`
`2) eachBlock(whatToDo1, 2000, 200)`

The only (and big) benefit you have of doing this is readability - NB: your code is not erroneous at all, it's well-formatted (except for what you were asking in this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return whatToDo;` in your “faster” example causes both loops to be skipped immediately and the function to exit. They don’t have the same effect, so your benchmark doesn’t apply.

How to do it, anyways: pass a function, call the function. There’s not a huge distinction in JavaScript, which is one of its most useful features.

```
function eachBlock(whatToDo, totalX, totalY) {
    for (var y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
             /* Fake operation for theory */
             whatToDo(y, x);
        }
    }
}

function basicFunc() {
    var totalX = 2000, totalY = 2000;
    eachoBlock(function(y, x) {
        var fakeVar = (y * x);
        …
    }, totalX, totalY);
}
```

Comment: Excellent point; removed. Benchmark aside, what are your thoughts on the question at hand.

Comment: @user3223880: I’m still not sure what you’re trying to do, because passing a string to a function doesn’t evaluate the code in that string either. If you wanted a callback of some kind, you would pass in a function, not a string.

Comment: That's where I'm unsure. My errors aside (obviously a lot), what would be the easiest way to do that? I'd like to operations in `basicFunc` to more or less be inserted into the loop of `eachBlock` so that I can just call and pass it what to do each time that loop sequence is needed.

Comment: @user3223880: `eachoBlock(function() { /* do things */ }, totalX, totalY);` and in `eachoBlock`, `whatToDo();`. First-class functions.

Comment: Under a quick JSPerf/Litmus, this function calling was still a decent bit faster. Thank you for helping me realize how much I overthought the problem. Simple anonymous function passing is and will clean up this code by the hundreds of lines.